# Клуб по американскому футболу или клуб американского футбола

Tags: управление

Как вы считаете, как лучше сказать: клуб по американскому футболу или клуб американского футбола? Вариант "американский футбольный клуб" не подходит, так как "американский футбол" - отдельный вид спорта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Профессиональный футбольный клуб в США, играющий в американский футбол, входит в организацию «Национальная футбольная лига» (NFL).

Клуб Национальной футбольной лиги. Клуб NFL.

В общем случае, т. е. без принадлежности к лигам и дивизионам, команды и клубы именуются клубами и командами по американскому футболу:

> В условиях нестабильной экономической ситуации произошло
>   расформирование ряда клубов по американскому футболу в России.

Answer (score 0):

Мне не нравится ни то ни другое. Клуб он "все-таки чего", а не "по". "По футболу" бывает чемпионат, а не клуб. К тому же переход прилагательного в родительный без предлога - обычная практика. "Хоккейный дворец" - "дворец хоккея". Но "клуб футбола" тоже не лучший обьорот.

Здесь бы надо сказать просто "футбольный клуб", но это, понятно не вариант, поскольку речь идет об американском футболе.

Все-таки меньшее из зол - ***"Клуб американского футбола".*** Ну или вообще всю фразу поменять.